# node crashes with "ros does not seem to be running"

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have create a node, but each time I try and start it using a .launch file that just launches the node, I get:

```
process[simon_says_main_M_node-1]: started with pid [11354]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  ROS does not seem to be running
[simon_says_main_M_node-1] process has died [pid 11354, exit code -6, cmd /home/elsa/bax_ws/devel/lib/simon_says_main/simon_says_main_M_node __name:=simon_says_main_M_node __log:=/home/elsa/.ros/log/bed59e4c-873f-11ea-bd6a-305a3a7c519b/simon_says_main_M_node-1.log].
log file: /home/elsa/.ros/log/bed59e4c-873f-11ea-bd6a-305a3a7c519b/simon_says_main_M_node-1*.log
```

The log file does not exist. Using rosrun to launch the node gives the same result. The node *does* run on another computer, and both have the same setup of packages and so on as far as I can tell.

using rosrun results in:

```
[baxter - http://localhost:11311] elsa@Inanna:~/bax_ws$ rosrun simon_says_main simon_says_main_M_node 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  ROS does not seem to be running
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code for the node is:

```
#include <pluginlib/class_loader.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>

#include <moveit_msgs/DisplayRobotState.h>
#include <moveit_msgs/DisplayTrajectory.h>

#include <moveit_msgs/AttachedCollisionObject.h>
#include <moveit_msgs/CollisionObject.h>

#include <moveit_visual_tools/moveit_visual_tools.h>


#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>


/*
 To Run:
 1) start baxter
 2) rosrun baxter_tools enable_robot.py -e
 3) rosrun baxter_interface joint_trajectory_action_server.py
 4) roslaunch baxter_moveit_config demo_baxter.launch right_electric_gripper:=true left_electric_gripper:=true
 5) rosrun simon_says_main simon_says_main_M_node

 #get the current end effector coordinates
$ rostopic echo /robot/limb/right/endpoint_state 
*/

static const std::string PLANNING_GROUP_L = "left_arm";
static const std::string PLANNING_GROUP_R = "right_arm";

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group_L(PLANNING_GROUP_L);
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group_R(PLANNING_GROUP_R);

void dab()
  {
    //plan right arm
    geometry_msgs::Pose rp;
    rp.orientation.w = 0.67;
    rp.position.x = 0.357;
    rp.position.y = -0.08;
    rp.position.z = 0.39;
    move_group_R.setPoseTarget(rp);

    //plan left arm
    geometry_msgs::Pose lp;
    lp.orientation.w = 0.73;
    lp.position.x = 0.26;
    lp.position.y = 1.18;
    lp.position.z = 1.08;
    move_group_L.setPoseTarget(lp);
    
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan my_plan_R;
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan my_plan_L;

    bool success_R = (move_group_R.plan(my_plan_R) == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);
    bool success_L = (move_group_L.plan(my_plan_L) == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);

    ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing dab - right arm (pose goal) %s", success_R ? "" : "FAILED");
    ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing dab - left arm (pose goal) %s", success_L ? "" : "FAILED");

    move_group_L.move();
    move_group_R.move();

  /*
  DAB - RIGHT
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: 0.357449700371
        y: -0.0845383821871
        z: 0.398438102254
      orientation: 
        x: -0.347113539773
        y: -0.354022093046
        z: -0.548629443089
        w: 0.673191118715
  DAB - LEFT
      frame_id: ''
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: 0.265252415343
        y: 1.18807756952
        z: 1.08236724242
      orientation: 
        x: -0.260426879784
        y: 0.376068085189
        z: 0.494750557147
        w: 0.738899534301
  */
  }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move_group_interface_tutorial");
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

  printf("Hi!\n");

  moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface planning_scene_interface;

  //iffy, don't need
  //move_group.getCurrentState()->getJointModelGroup(PLANNING_GROUP);

  // Visualization: The package MoveItVisualTools provides many capabilities for visualizing objects, robots, and trajectories in RViz as well as debugging tools such as step-by-step introspection of a script.
  namespace rvt = rviz_visual_tools;
  moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools visual_tools("base");
  visual_tools.deleteAllMarkers();

  // Remote control is an introspection tool that allows users to step through a high level script via buttons and keyboard shortcuts in RViz
  visual_tools.loadRemoteControl();

  // RViz provides many types of markers, in this demo we will use text, cylinders, and spheres
  Eigen::Isometry3d text_pose = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();
  text_pose.translation().z() = 1.75;
  visual_tools.publishText(text_pose, "MoveGroupInterface Demo", rvt::WHITE, rvt::XLARGE);

  // Batch publishing is used to reduce the number of messages being sent to RViz for large visualizations
  visual_tools.trigger();

  // Getting Basic Information:  We can print the name of the reference frame for this robot.
  ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Planning frame: %s", move_group_L.getPlanningFrame().c_str());

  // We can also print the name of the end-effector link for this group.
  ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "End effector link: %s", move_group_L.getEndEffectorLink().c_str());

  // We can get a list of all the groups in the robot:
  ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Available Planning Groups:");
  std::copy(move_group_L.getJointModelGroupNames().begin(), move_group_L.getJointModelGroupNames().end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
  std::copy(move_group_R.getJointModelGroupNames().begin(), move_group_R.getJointModelGroupNames().end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));

  // Start the demo
  visual_tools.prompt("Press 'next' in the RvizVisualToolsGui window to start the demo");

  dab();
  
  printf(":D nice!\n");

  return 0;
};
```

Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide or any other ways I can help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350643/node-crashes-with-%22ros-does-not-seem-to-be-running%22/) by [DaxJadz](https://answers.ros.org/users/54020/daxjadz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-26**:
I'm not entirely sure, but you appear to be initialising two `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface` instances as global variables (`move_group_L` and `move_group_R`), which could be causing the error you get. `MoveGroupInterface` as part of its initialisation requires certain ROS functionality, and if you haven't initialised ROS *before* creating those `MoveGroupInterface`s, they will likely complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The comment by Gvdhoom and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/100656/problem-with-nodehandle-before-rosinit/) question that has a different error message but the same underlying problem cleared it up for me.
**The Cause:** Some of my global variables were objects that created NodeHandle objects within their internal implementation. Since they are global variables, they were constructed before main (and ros::init()) were run.

**The Solution:** I changed

```
static const std::string PLANNING_GROUP_L = "left_arm";

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group_L(PLANNING_GROUP_L);
```

To

```
static const std::string PLANNING_GROUP_L = "left_arm";

moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface *move_group_L;

void setup()
{
left_arm = new moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface(PLANNING_GROUP_L);
}
```

And replaced any `left_arm.<something>` with `left_arm-><something>`. I also found that making a global `tf2_ros::TransformListener` and `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster` cause the same issue, and are fixable with the same solution above.

---

Originally posted by [DaxJadz](https://answers.ros.org/users/54020/daxjadz/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0